# Prove determinant is negative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

Prove that the determinant $\Delta$ is negative

> $$
> \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
> a & b & c \\
> b & c & a \\
> c & a & b
> \end{vmatrix}<0
> $$

where $a,b,c$ are positive and $a\neq b\neq c$.

**My Attempt:**

Applying Sarrus' rule,
$$
\begin{matrix}
a&b&c&a&b\\
b&c&a&b&c\\
c&a&b&c&a
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
\Delta=acb+bac+cba-c^3-a^3-b^3=3abc-(a^3+b^3+c^3)\\
=-\Big[(a^3+b^3+c^3)-3abc\Big]
$$
How do I prove that $(a^3+b^3+c^3)-3abc>0$ thus prove $\Delta<0$ ?

Comment: You could also solve this one geometrically. Consider rotation around the line $x=y=z$ by $120$ degrees. It exchanges $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates of a vector and under it $(b,c,a)^T$ is the image of $(a,b,c)^T$ and $(c,a,b)^T$ is the image of $(b,c,a)^T$. With a bit of magic and imagination you can see that the basis made of these vectors is left handed and thus $\Delta < 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality):

$$
\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3} = abc
$$

The *strict* inequality holds unless $\,a=b=c\,$.

Comment: thanx. I was only aware of this inequality involving two elements. Could u pls direct me to prove AM-GM inequality for $n$ elements.

Comment: There are proofs a the link provided, @ss1729

Comment: @ss1729 See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_by_induction) for proofs by induction.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3 abc = (a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca),$$ where the first term is certainly positive. For the second term, observe $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab-bc-ca = \frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2),$$ which is also positive.

Comment: This is Gauß' identity…

Comment: @Bernard I wasn't aware this identity had a name - furthermore I can't find a reference for this.

Comment: Well, I always heard of it under this name, and I used to give it as a standard exercise on algebraic factoring to my students, simply because I had to do it myself in high school. If you read  French, there's this Wikipedia page [Identité remarquable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identité_remarquable), which unfortunately doesn't seem to have an equivalent in English.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, I'd been familiar with it as an identity (although here AM-GM is certainly more appropriate), but not by this name. Thanks!